# SQL / Joomla Database Query - Translation Required from Pseudocode

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to solve a problem with a Joomla Component and I've sort of come up with a solution that I think might work, it's just that my coding isn't good enough to make it work - anyway, feel free to let me know if my solution is flawed or suggest an alternative...

So I've written some pseudo-code in the hope that someone with experience might be able to translate it for me, if you fancy a bit of a challenge that is...

I'm using PhocaDownload (A component that lets users organise files for download into various categories) It displays a number in brackets next to each category that displays the number of items in that category like so: 
Category Name (12 items)

However the issue is, when a category has subcategories below it this number just shows (0) or whatever the number of items that are directly within that category. It doesn't count the number of items in its subcategories.

I want to add up all the items in any subcategories and display a total of all the items so it doesn't look like there's (0) items in a category when in fact they are plenty of items, it's just that they are in further subcategories.

So here's how I imagine it would work (please remember this is just my notes):

```
$catid = $this->category
// Count number of items in category
$totals = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `#__phocadownload` WHERE `catid` = $catid

// Check if there are any subcategories
SELECT `id` FROM `#__phocadownload_categories` WHERE `parent_id` = $catid
Store results in [ARRAY]

// If subcategories exist, loop through each and add the number of items in to the running total
if [ARRAY] not empty {
    foreach [ITEM IN ARRAY]
        $totals = $totals + SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `#__phocadownload` WHERE `catid` = [ITEM IN ARRAY] 
    End foreach
}
// Output combined total of items in this category and any subcategories
return $totals
```

What I need to know is how to connect to the database and what the exact code should be to query this information from the database, where should this code be put and how can I access the result in the default.php template?

Hopefully this makes sense to somebody!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the database structure for Phoca Downloads but can take a look tomorrow if need be. I wrote this query based on Joomla's Article Manager which is the same concept as what you have described in your question:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select( array('catid', 'COUNT(*)') )
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
      ->group($db->quoteName('catid'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadRowList();

foreach(array_slice($results,1) as $row) {
    echo $row[1];
}
```

So lets says I have the following structure:

```
Parent category
    Child category 1
        article 1
        article 2
        article 3
    Child category 2
        article 1
        article 2
```

The above query will output:

```
3   << articles in category 1
2   << articles in category 2
```

As you can see, I used `array_slice` int he `foreach` loops which excludes the first value (`1`) which will be outputted.

So here's a structure for you. You will of course need to change `#__content` to `#__phocadownload` and possibly make another tweak or 2 to suit your needs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to follow your suggestion but I can't actually seem to work out how this will get the items from the child categories? This will just count the items in the current category won't it because you haven't used the parent_id anywhere? 

I don't want to output how many in each category, I just want to total up all items in the current category and any of its subcategories within that.

The table names and the column names required for this query are basically as in my pseudocode (names are correct), if you can follow it.